# how to display blackshashes in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to display a network share path in my Prolog output code.

The path is like :

```
\\fileserver\path\to\file.txt  (ex1)

        or
\\\\fileserver\\path\\to\\file.txt  (ex2)
```

but If I try displaying it using format :

```
pri(Z):-
    format('Printing Zx : \"~w\"',[Z]).
```

the slashes get truncated to

```
\fileserverpathtofile.txt (ex1)
```

Obviously some times, the path may contain `\\\\` in which case the display is correct.

How to make it print proper path?

Any help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Weird. I just tried `format('Printing Zx : \"~w\"', ['\\\\fileserver\\path\\to\\file.txt']).` in the SWI-Prolog toplevel and it works fine. Are you sure the backslashes are being properly read-in in the first place? Also, you don't need to escape double quotes inside a single-quoted atom like that.

Comment: if there are four slashes, it works fine. but this path comes to me from external source and sometimes I get only \\fileserver\path\to\file.txt , in which case single slashes get stripped off. that is the problem

Comment: trying using this one format('Printing Zx : \"~w\"', ['\\fileserver\path\to\file.txt'])

Comment: If the data comes from an external source, it's not a literal and should not be treated as such by the interpreter. '\\\\fileserver\\path\\to\\file.txt' is simply a literal for '\\fileserver\path\to\file.txt'.

Comment: Just out of scope , how to disable open bounty?

Comment: Bounty: you can't - the idea is you pay it, so that more people look at your question.

Comment: do not Forget that in Windows `/` usually works equally well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Prolog atoms backslash is a meta-character, i.e. if you want your atom to contain a backslash character then you need to escape it using the backslash character. E.g. in order to represent the Windows path `\\fileserver\path\to\file.txt` as a Prolog atom you need to write

```
Path = '\\\\fileserver\\path\\to\\file.txt'.
```

In principle there are two ways of printing stuff out, one for the humans (pretty-printing), using `write`

```
?- Path = '\\\\fileserver\\path\\to\\file.txt', write(Path).
\\fileserver\path\to\file.txt
```

and one for the machines (serializing), using `write_canonical`

```
?- Path = '\\\\fileserver\\path\\to\\file.txt', write_canonical(Path).
'\\\\fileserver\\path\\to\\file.txt'
```

`write_canonical` makes sure that Prolog can read the output back into the same exact atom.

Your problem seems to be that you do not correctly represent the path in Prolog. If the path comes from an external source, you first need to escape it (add a backslash in front of every backslash) before you can store it as a Prolog atom.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to add backslah in front of every backslash using any predicate in Prolog?

Comment: As far as I know there is no built-in predicate that would allow you to modify Prolog atoms like this, i.e. you need to implement this yourself: split the atom into a list of characters, walk through this list building a new list that has an additional backslash for every backslash, convert this list back into an atom.